# flutter addAll isn't defined for Iterable

Tags: json, flutter, datamodel

I need your help for the following problem on line 22.
Flutter says, that "addAll isn't defined for Iterable". What do I need to change in my code or do you need additional Information?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/jsonApi/dataModels/dataModelPlaces.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/jsonApi/parsers/repositoryPlaces.dart';

class ShareAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShareAppScreenState createState() => _ShareAppScreenState();
}

class _ShareAppScreenState extends State<ShareAppScreen> {
  //List<DataModelPlaces> _places = <DataModelPlaces>[];
  Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _places = <DataModelPlaces>[];
  Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _placesDisplay = <DataModelPlaces>[];

  bool _isPlacesLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPlaces().then((pvalue) {
      setState(() {
        _isPlacesLoading = false;
        _places.addAll(pvalue); //<- here I have a problem that addAll isn't defined for Iterable
        _placesDisplay = _places;
        print('User display pin Records: ${pvalue.data!.length}');
        var i=0;
        while (i < pvalue.data!.length){
          print('User display Lat of $i: ${pvalue.data![i].attributes!.latitude}');
          print('User display Long of $i: ${pvalue.data![i].attributes!.latitude}');
          i++;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  List stocksList = [
    CompanyStocks(name: "Intel Corp", price: 56.96),
    CompanyStocks(name: "HP Inc", price: 32.43),
    CompanyStocks(name: "Apple Inc", price: 133.98),
    CompanyStocks(name: "Microsoft Corporation", price: 265.51)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Users List ${_places.length}'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(

          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: stocksList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      stocksList[index].name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(
                        stocksList[index].name[0],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: Text("\$ ${stocksList[index].price}"),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CompanyStocks {
  String name;
  double price;

  CompanyStocks({required this.name,required this.price});
}
```

At the End I would need an Variable "_places" and "_placesDisplay" of DataModelPlaces which I can use in in Place of the List "stocksList" which is working but not _places / _placesDisplay"

Many Thanks

Roman

Comment: Iterable doesn't have `addAll` method. See https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable-class.html . Use `List` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterable does not have `.addAll`. <del>You need to convert it to a `List` first so you can addAll the elements to it such as:</del>

**Update: My bad. `toList()` will return a new list! You should try the alternative approach below**

```dart
// This wrong since it will return a new list (wrong)
// _places.toList().addAll(pvalue)
```

Alternatively, you can change the definition to be `List` instead of `Iterable`:

from:

```dart
Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _places = <DataModelPlaces>[];
Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _placesDisplay = <DataModelPlaces>[];
```

To:

```dart
List<DataModelPlaces> _places = <DataModelPlaces>[];
List<DataModelPlaces> _placesDisplay = <DataModelPlaces>[];
```

Update:

As discussed in the comments, you want to make sure that `fetchPlaces` is returning an `Iterable` in order to use `_places.addAll(pvalue)` otherwise, if it's a single object, use `_places.add(pvaule)`.

Comment: I have tried that but then I got the Error "The Argument type 'DataModelPlaces' can't be assigned to the parameter type of 'Iterable<DataModelPlaces>', Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SecurexpertsNETworkGoogle where is the error occurring exactly? If it's occurring at `_places.addAll(pvalue)` make sure that `pvalue` (aka `fetchPlaces`) is actually giving you an Iterable or a List but not a single value of `DataModelPlaces`. If it's as single value, you can simply use `.add` instead of `.addAll`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion.
  Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _places = <DataModelPlaces>[];
  Iterable<DataModelPlaces> _placesDisplay = <DataModelPlaces>[];
with
    fetchPlaces().then((pvalue) {
      setState(() {
        _places.toList().add(pvalue);
        _placesDisplay = _places;
        }
      });
    });
  }
But it is not filling up the _places array. In the pvalue the whole array is visible. Any other Suggestions?

Comment: @SecurexpertsNETworkGoogle Yeah it won't because `toList()` is generating a new list. Do the alternative approach I mentioned above (i.e. change `Iterable<DataModelPlaces>` to `List<DataModelPlaces>` for both `_places` and `_placesDisplay`). Then you can remove `toList()` and add `pvalue` directly to `_places` such as  `_places.add(pvalue)`.

Comment: I've updated it my answer and my bad for the confusion.

Comment: Great it works!. I have now _places and _placesDisplay arrays. This is great. I have just an additional question. the Array _places and _placesDisplay have a leading 0 in the structure. Means I need to get values with _places[0].data!.length. Is there any chance to get rid of the [0] put it into _places.data!.length?

Comment: @SecurexpertsNETworkGoogle ... you could create another list and add all `places[0].data` to it. There's just not enough information here to know what `data` is (type wise). Or maybe modify `fetchPlaces` to return a list of places so then you can use `_places.addAll(pvalue)`  and `_places.length` directly  (assuming `data` is `Iterable<DataModelPlaces>`).